# Openpyxl Python - Vlookup Iterate through rows

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to automate a daily report we have, and I'm using a query to pull in data and writing it in Excel using openpyxl, and then doing a vlookup in openpyxl to match a cell value. Unfortunately I'm hung up on how to iterate through the rows to find the cell value to look up.

```
for row in ws['E5:E91']:
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = "=VLOOKUP(D5, 'POD data'!C1:D87, 2, FALSE)"
```

It works except I don't know how to change the `D5` value to look up `D6`, `D7`, `D8`, etc. depending on the row I'm on. I'm honestly at a loss for how to best approach this. Obviously I don't feel like writing the formula out for every single row, and there's other columns I'd like to do this for once I get it.

Comment: The formula is just a string, so use a counter or `cell.row` and substitute out the "5"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your example, you can do:

```
for row in ws['E5:E91']:
    for cell in row:
       cell.value = "=VLOOKUP(D{0}, 'POD data'!C1:D87, 2, FALSE)".format(cell.row)
```

Comment: That solved it. Not sure why I didn't think of that! Thanks!

Comment: You could also cheat the way Excel does and create shared formulae.